# Python AttributeError: property cannot overwrite inherited attribute?

Tags: python, properties

I still don't fully understand when and how to use properties. Here I have a class `SpecialCar` which is inheriting `Car`. The variable `summer_tire` should basically be equivalent to `tire`, except for the name. So whenever I am asking for either of those two, I want to get `summer_tire`.

Using `@property` results in an error. Deleting the `@property` line will print `0`, but I want to get `2`.

```
class Car():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tire = 0

class SpecialCar(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        Car.__init__(self)
        self.summer_tire = 2
        self.winter_tire = 5

    @property
    def tire(self):
        return self.summer_tire

i = SpecialCar()
print(i.tire)
```

Comment: Not an answer, but worth asking, if the property isn't computed why is it not a "real" property?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared a property that doesn't have a setter, thus `self.tire = 0` in `Car.__init__` fails.

You could give your new `property` a setter:

```
class SpecialCar(Car):
    def __init__(self):
        Car.__init__(self)
        self.summer_tire = 2
        self.winter_tire = 5

    @property
    def tire(self):
        return self.summer_tire

    @tire.setter
    def tire(self, new_tire):
        self.summer_tire = new_tire
```

or you could avoid calling `Car.__init__` altogether, or make `Car.tire` a *class* attribute, set as part of the class and replaced with the `property` in subclasses.